# How to replace the instanceof keyword with polymorphism?

Tags: java

```
        while (Board[randRow][randColumn] instanceof Wumpus || Board[randRow][randColumn] instanceof Gold
                || Board[randRow][randColumn] instanceof Pit)
```

How do I replace the instanceof with polymorphism?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. You could call a method that is defined in a common baseclass, e.g. `Board[randRow][randColumn].foo()`, where `foo()` is abstract in a common interface or abstract super-class and implemented in every subclasses.

Comment: If you're interested in checking concrete types simply add this checkings as seperate methods and override them in each subclass. Because these checkings are part of your business logic

Answer (score 2):

What is common for `Wumpus`, `Gold` and `Pit` ?
Lets say that bot/monster is interested in cell's of this type.

So define an interface:

```
public interface Cell{
    boolean isInterestedForMonster();
}
```

And implement it for `Wumpus`, `Gold` and `Pit`:

```
public class Gold implements Cell{
    @Override public boolean isInterestedForMonster(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
Cell cell = Board[randRow][randColumn];
while(cell.isInterestedForMonster()){
    //Do something
}
```

This is how you can replace 'instanceof' with polymorphism